# Netty Decoding failed DefaultFullHttpRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, webflux

I am currently developing using spring boot webflux. I am using websocket clients and APIs clients, but this error occurs a few hours after deployment. I couldn't figure out where this error was coming from. Where does this problem come from?

The error log is as below.

```
[reactor-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [9c0c3ede, L:/172.25.0.8:8080 - R:/94.232.43.63:34534] Decoding failed: DefaultFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)), version: HTTP/1.0, content: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0))
GET /bad-request HTTP/1.0 :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:65) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:126) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:273) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec$HttpServerRequestDecoder.decode(HttpServerCodec.java:140) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507) ~[netty-codec-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446) ~[netty-codec-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
```

Sometimes broken characters are also found along with the sentence 'text is empty'.
If this is an encoding issue, how should I set it up?

Comment: did you get any solution for this issue? I am facing the same issue that it fails while decoding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be running the spring boot app on `http` only and then hitting it via `https` (or your browser is redirecting to https), so the http version is not parsed appropriately. You should have also:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: S���JZ
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:116) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.73.Final.jar!/:4.1.73.Final]
```

Please assure the proper browser/request/protocol/encoding.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes how the errors description can be so misleading

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue to occur, when was delegating all headers from one microservice to another. Now had removed this and i'm selecting specific headers for delegating further.